# Upload a file to a server

Tags: coldfusion, path, coldfusion-9, cffile

I want the user to upload files to server.

In the destination path of cffile I am giving it as \servername\folder\filename.

However, it doesn't recognize this path. Any suggestions?

Comment: What account is the ColdFusion service running under? That account needs to have write access to your file destination.

Comment: What operating system are you running? Are you able to use cffile to create files? Try that first before debugging uploads

Comment: I am on Windows XP.

The server I am trying to upload to is in the network.
I can access the server folders directly if I give a path directly through Windows explorer, however cffile gives me invalid destination error...

Answer (score 1):

don't you need two leading slashes for a UNC path?
\\servername\path\to\file\

in your example you only have;
\servername.....

Otherwise, as other have suggested it might be a permissions error.
I have only just been using CFFILE yesterday and today, using a UNC path to the server.

Also, what OS is the server, there are some oddities sometimes when trying to attach to a MS-Server. Eg. If you;re using a fully qualified domain name for SERVERNAME, try just the computer name. Or vice-versa...